# Split String using scanner or regular expression java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like follow:

```
AddStudent,addingToListAddStudent,FD,M,fdsq,fdsq,85/26/9541,fdsq,842-568 523,fdqs,fdqs,fdsq,fdsq,4,MAT101,Math 101,Mr. Smith,20,3.15,1,Computer Science Bsc,120
```

(all in one line)

I would like to get rid of the "AddStuent,addingToListAddStudent". My problem is that the string can vary in size. I can have more elements separated by commas. I looked into using reuglare expression but I can't get it to work. I tired using this regular expression but I'm not sure how to use it:

```
/([^,]+)/
```

**Solution**

I've used Tom's answer easy, fast and clean, since my string is always going to have the same 2 first elements. So I used this:

```
string.replace("AddStudent,addingToListAddStudent,", "");
```

What is the most conventional way of doing it ? using string replace or the regular expression ?

Comment: will "AddStudent,addingToListAddStudent" always be at the beginning of the string?

Comment: How about `string.replace("AddStudent,addingToListAddStudent,", "");`?

Comment: Yes it will always be, its is a "command" that I send to a server

Comment: U can use "^.+,.+.,"

Comment: string.replace(string, string) or string.substring(int begin index)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split the string(As your question title suggests). Use string.split(","), this will return an array of strings ex: `{"AddStudent" , "addingToListAddStudent" , ...}`

Then you can convert it to a list:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(string.split(","));
```

And then you can remove the first and second elements.

Otherwise, if you only want to remove  AddStudent,addingToListAddStudent then use

```
string.replace("AddStudent,addingToListAddStudent,", "");
```

Comment: Regex solution at least for me looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing it very often you can use String.replace() else if you are using it very often you should compile a regex for it and replace it by the regex. It is much more performant